# Error running npm install or npm update on alfresco-content-app project

Tags: node.js, angular, alfresco

When cloning the alfresco-content-app project and trying to run the npm install or npm update command, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/user/Desktop/Project/alfresco-content-app/node_modules/typescript
npm ERR! dest /home/user/Desktop/Project/alfresco-content-app/node_modules/.typescript-6JRemK6E
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/user/Desktop/ Project/alfresco-content-app/node_modules/typescript' -> '/home/user/Desktop/Project/alfresco-content-app/node_modules/.typescript-6JRemK6E'
```

[image]

1. Clone the alfresco-content-app project:

   git clone https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-content-app.git
2. Enter the directory created after cloning:

   cd alfresco-content-app
3. Run the npm install or npm update command:

   npm install or npm update